# What's the good way to call multiple apis and return a list of errors if it has in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a elixir project and I would like to implement a function, which will call multiple external apis and return the list of errors.

Suppose I have serval call api functions:

- create_via_api_a
- create_via_api_b
- create_via_api_c
- ...

And each api function will return `:ok` or `error`. My main function will return `[error_a, error_b, error_d, ...]`.

Currently my solution is using `++` to connect each API Call. And I have a `case` function to control the returns.

For example:

```
def create_via_api_a do
  case API.create(xxx) do
    :ok -> []
    error -> error
  end
end
```

But It looks a little weird. I am not sure if there is any elixir idioms to implement this? such as `pipe` or `with` etc?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [`Task.async_stream/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html?#async_stream/3) if API calls could be performed in parallel (read: are independent on each other.)

Somewhat along these lines would work.

```rb
apis
|> Task.async_stream(& &1.create(xxx))
|> Enum.reduce([], fn
  :ok, acc -> acc
  error, acc -> [error | acc]
end)
```

---

Example with different APIs

```rb
[{API1, :create, [42]}, {API2, :call, []}]
|> Task.async_stream(fn {m, f, a} -> apply(m, f, a) end)
|> Enum.reduce([], fn
  :ok, acc -> acc
  error, acc -> [error | acc]
end)
```

---

If it should be done synchronously, omit the `Task` invocation

```rb
apis
|> Enum.reduce([], fn {m, f, a}, acc ->
  case apply(m, f, a) do
    :ok, acc -> acc
    error, acc -> [error | acc]
  end
end)
|> Enum.reverse()
```

And, finally, if you want to stop on the first error, use [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#reduce_while/3).